# How I can obtain that equation "2.0"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

I'm studying analysis and in particular I need to prove that if $A$ is the set of $q$ positive elements lower than $\sqrt{2}$ then $A$ has no upper element, and if $B$ is the set of all $Q$ elements larger than $\sqrt{2}$ then $B$ has no lower element.

The idea is that if $p$ is in $A$, then exist $q$ in $A$ such that $q > p$ and $q^2 < 2$ and vice versa.

My book shows that in $2$ equations

(1) $q = p - (p^2 - 2)/(p + 2)$

(2) $q^2 = 2 + (p^2 - 2)/(p + 2)^2$

When (2) is $(1)^2$ but I ask why not just

$q = (p + \sqrt{2})/2$?

Comment: ... because that would certainly make $q$ irrational i you start with rational $p$

Comment: u.u yes is true

Answer (score 1):

You are working in the rational numbers, so you need $q$ to be rational.  If $p$ is rational your expression fails this.